# Discover all services in the network using android NSD

Tags: android, nsd

I´m trying to find all services in the network using:

```
mNsdManager.discoverServices(
            SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
```

but you have to define SERVICE_TYPE for example:

```
public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.";
```

so it will discover all http services using tcp, but it wouldn´t find https services at the same time or any other kind of services

how can i set all this in order to find any service using tcp?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I am using

```
private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_services._dns-sd._udp";
```

which gives me a list of all available services on the LAN:

```
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _workstation, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _UnoWiFi, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _udisks-ssh, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _airplay, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _raop, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _xbmc-events, type: _udp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _xbmc-jsonrpc, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _xbmc-jsonrpc-h, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _http, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _sftp-ssh, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _ssh, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
D/MHC-NSD: Service discovery found: name: _arduino, type: _tcp.local., host: null, port: 0
```